# php web project Running on server But page Not found

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to run a php project with database on my server for learning purpose. After setting up xampp I pasted the **project file[filename: HRMS-FRESH]** in ***htdocs/*** folder, Afterwards I made a database( same name as the sql file name ) and imported the database file. The import was successfully performed [sql file Import success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrk2e.png)
Now when I went to **http://localhost/HRMS-FRESH** it said

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> ---
>
> Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.1 Server at localhost
> Port 80

I thought the project page would appear but it didn't

Here is the Picture of HRMS-FRESH directory

[HRMS-FRESH directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJESY.png)

.htaccess
[.htaccess file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTDUE.png)

Comment: if its on a server your url wont be http://localhost/HRMS-FRESH. It will be your domain or possibly the server ip. Have you configured an apache virtual host at all?

Comment: @Wakka you don't have to do that, it will use default config for all domains

Comment: @Unsure Me does HRMS-FRESH contain index.php file or index.html? what do you mean by "project file"? show your files/directory structure.

Comment: Why is Xampp on the server at all though? It's a server emulator.

Comment: @Wakka no, its not an emulator, it's server package... it's "X" (Cross-Platform) Apache HTTP server + MySQL server + PHP + Perl (XAMPP)

Comment: @FlashThunder I added a picture of the directory and files in HRMS-FRESH folder. It does contain an index.php file

Comment: try http://localhost/HRMS-FRESH/index.php and show me the content of `.htaccess` file

Comment: @FlashThunder I tried but still same problem page 404 Not Found. I added .htaccess file. on the end of question description

Comment: ok then, `.htaccess` seems fine, attach `apache.conf`, let's check this

Answer (score 0):

Try localhost/folderOfYourProject/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check Your localhost first

try input http://localhost in browser and you will get xampp first page.

If alright remove that .htacess from your folder and try http://localhost/HRMS-FRESH/index.php it must run if everything is okey. IF it run check your .htacess file and did you enable it on xampp ? IF not google how to enable it, once it is done put back your .htaccess and check your site. It must work :))

Comment: htaccess is fine and it's not a reason

Comment: Then make sure database is connected properly and up running ...

Comment: it's surely not about database :)

Comment: Then check php.ini and config.ini respectively check the log of xampp you will get the reason..

Comment: Maybe stop answering me like I would ask the question, as I did not :)

Comment: okey .. that's it